# C lib to read and parse JSON directly from file stream

Tags: c, json, parsing, cjson

I have seen a number of libs for parsing JSON in C but none of them can read and parse directly from file streams. The problem with all such libs e.g Yajl, cjson is that if the json document in the file is huge then you have to first read all of that into a memory buffer and then run the APIs provided by these libs to parse it.

There APIs often look like

```
cJSON *cJSON_Parse(const char *value)
```

which take a char* to a buffer.

I want to avoid that since my files can be very large and i donot know the sizes of the files in advance. Moreover, these libs maintain reference to objects,arrays in the actual buffer to retrieve the values so i cannot free the original buffer.

Is there a JSON parsing lib that can read and parse directly from file streams?

Comment: Look at these, if you haven't yet: [jsonsl](https://github.com/mnunberg/jsonsl), [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/), [cson](http://fossil.wanderinghorse.net/repos/cson/index.cgi/index), [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c), [json-parser](https://github.com/udp/json-parser), [jsmn](http://zserge.bitbucket.org/jsmn.html). I haven't looked at their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the file to the process using **mmap()** and then simply using the address returned to carry out the **char*** manipulations makes all of them useful and a good way to solve the problem

Comment: Do all systems have `mmap()`? The question doesn't seem to specify a particular OS.

Comment: what system doesn't have it?

Answer (score 3):

http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/ is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Haven't tested it, but +1 since it looks like it applies very well.

Comment: I mentioned this above in my comment. If you look at its API it operates on char* for a buffer in memory. Not on files

Comment: If you're after the JSON equivalent of a SAX parser for XML, then yajl is what you're after. See the callbacks you would implement: http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/yajl-2.0.1/structyajl__callbacks.html

Comment: Here's what looks like example code that demonstrates the use of yajl as an event-based (SAX) parser: http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/yajl-2.0.1/reformatter_2json_reformat_8c-example.html

Comment: @auny: But you can read the file in small pieces, you don't have to read the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: I just solved the issue with a better approach. i mapped(mmap) the file into my process and then used the address for char* manipulation.